# Как отправить JSON файл на локальный HTTP сервер

Tags: html, json, node.js, сервер

Я запустил локальный сервер http-server и по ссылке http://192.168.1.49:8080/index.html открывается сайт, а как на него отправить JSON и уже в коде html'a получить этот JSON, не знаю. Использую Node.js

Comment: Что сервер делает? Как принимает? Нельзя просто так запустить сервер и слать всё что хочешь! ;) Короче, мало инфы

Comment: У меня есть сервер в node js
http.createServer((req,res)=>{}).listen(8080);
Как на него отправить json  и как этот самый json обработать в html сайта

Comment: Ого... Ну я просто ссылочек накидаю тогда, ок? )) [Express](https://expressjs.com/) поможет организовать код сервера. Там есть пример элементарного сервера. [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) поможет на этот сервер с фронта что-то отправить. Это слишком ёмкий вопрос. Так что читай потихоньку. Видосы посмотри на ютубе. В двух словах не описать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: `const server = http.createServer ((req, res) => { 

    if (req.url == '/ now') { 

        res.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': 'application / json'}); 
        res .write (JSON.stringify ({now: new Date ()})); 
        res.end (); 

    } else { 

        res.end ('Invalid request'); 
    } 
});`
Нашёл не большой пример, не могу понять, как я буду отправлять запрос  '/ now'